# c# Как импортировать группу методов из файла внутрь класса?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

```
namespace p1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ....код, различающийся для разных проектов
        }


        public static void metod1
        ....методы, одинаковые для всех проектов
        public static void metod199
    }
}
```

"методы, одинаковые для всех проектов" будут содержаться в одном файле, но использоваться всеми проектами.
Как это организовать?
Все должно происходить в одном классе "Program".
Без импорта классов.
Мож как то можно импортировать кусок кода C# прям из текстового файла?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону CSharpCodeProvider

Comment: то есть вам нужен один базовый класс `ProgramBase`, от которого вы будете наследовать все ваши проекты?

Comment: @tym32167 Все проекты будут наследовать большую часть методов в классе. Но процедура Main будет разная для всех, внутри базового класса

Comment: Ответ на [английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4181855/6468198)

Comment: Еще можно сделать Program partial классом, расписать методы в отдельном файле и ссылаться на этот отдельный файл из своих проектов.